# Create a custom /etc/init.d script in Debian 10 Buster

Tags: debian, systemd, init.d, lsb, debian-buster

I need to develop an `/etc/init.d` script to start and stop a server (binary executable) in Debian 10 Buster.  Whereas in earlier versions of Debian, you would write a complete shell script that issues calls to `'start-stop-daemon'`, in recent releases these mechanics seem to be have been abstracted away.  The manual page `'init-d-script'` gives a simple script that will start and stop a server based on setting a single variable `'DAEMON'`.

However I need to customise by writing a lock file to disc after the server starts, change the current working directory and pass a custom argument to the server.

The manual page refers to developing override functions such as `'do_start_override'` and `'do_stop_override'` which presumably are called instead of the default functions.  How should I approach writing an override function?  Should I copy and paste the function `'do_start_cmd()'` from `'/lib/init/init-d-script'` and modify it?  Or should I call the function `'start_daemon()'` that is defined in `'/lib/lsb/init-functions'`?

Comment: Don't write ancient init.d scripts anymore, just make a systemd unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smartass response:

```
apt-get install sysvinit-core
```

Disclaimer: I have not done this on Buster, don't try it on an important system.

Assuming you'd like to stick with the new default since Jessie, [systemd](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd), [the init.d scripts are not the preferred method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581). [Configuring a systemd service unit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47715) would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, so my options were to roll back to the older System V init system by installing `sysvinit-core`, then write an `/etc/init.d` script, or stick with the new `systemd` and write a service unit file? I have done the latter, and it proved pretty straightforward.

Comment: The switch to systemd has been a bit controversial, as it doesn't add much beyond complexity for the average server, hence the smartass part. ;-) It has its merits on more dynamic systems, like a desktop. But neither is inherently better.